# sigma notation for sumsets $\Sigma B$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, additive-combinatorics, sumset

I am reading a number theory paper about sumsets [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.01905)].  If $A, B \in \mathbb{Z}$ are two sets of integers we can define:
$$ A + B = \{ a + b : a \in A, b \in B \} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$$
what do you think they mean by sigma notation for subsets.  The paper has the notation:
$$ \sum_{i \in I} B_i \subseteq A $$
could that mean the [sumset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset) of all the sets $B_i$ with $i \in I$ ? There are no numbers to add quite yet.

Comment: Since $I$ is finite, say $I = \{i_1,\dotsc,i_k\}$, it's just the $\operatorname{card} I$-fold sum $$B_{i_1} + B_{i_2} + \dotsc + B_{i_k}.$$